# How to import go interface package in my main.go?

Tags: go, interface, grpc, go-micro

For clarity most of the code is removed to focus more on the question. I have a `go-micro` server file called `main.go` with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/micro/go-micro"
    "github.com/micro/go-micro/server"

    proto "mypkg/proto"
)

const serviceName = "SRV"

func main() {
    service := micro.NewService(
        micro.Name(strings.ToLower(serviceName)),
        micro.Server(
            server.NewServer(
                server.Name(strings.ToLower(serviceName))
            ),
        ),
    )

    service.Init()

    if err := proto.RegisterSRVServiceHandler(service.Server(), new(SRVService)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := service.Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**SRVService** is in another file called `srv_service.go` (with the same package name) and I don't know how to import it:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    proto "mypkg/proto"
)

type SRVService struct{}

func (g *SRVService) AddUser(ctx context.Context, req *proto.AddUserRequest, rsp *proto.AddUserResponse) error {
    rsp.UserId = "12312331231"
    return nil
}
```

How should I access `SRVService` in `main.go`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're in the same folder, they're part of the same package (their package declaration must reflect that). If they are part of the same package, you don't need to import anything. You can refer to all identifiers (being exported or not) from the package.

The `main` package is special though. If your `main` package consists of multiple files, you have to list all when running or building the app, e.g.:

```
go run srv_service.go main.go
```

Comment: I forgot to run it like you said and it works, thank you. Isn't there any other way to run just `main.go` and it automatically fetches `SRVService`?

Comment: Or simply `go run .`, then you don't have to list all the files all the time.